# Create a list in prolog

Tags: prolog

How would I implement shoppinglist, based on the Holiday passed in, it should return a list for all ingredients in all sides for that holiday.

For example, shoppinglist(halloween, X) should return sugar, water.

```
/* Facts */

sides(halloween, candy).
sides(halloween, soda).

ingredient(candy, sugar).
ingredient(soda, water).


/* Rules */
/* return a list of all ingredients needed for holiday */
shoppinglist(Holiday, List) :-
```

Comment: First do it for a single ingredient...

Comment: At the Prolog prompt, after loading in your facts, try some manual queries, like `sides(holloween).` Then try, `sides(holloween, X), ingredient(X, Ingredient).` and when prompted with possible answers, press `;`.